# $X_n \to X$ in distribution, show: $X_n +c \to X+c$ in distribution

Tags: probability

It is a very simple question but I somehow got stuck on it. Say $X_n, X$ are random variables, such that $X_n \to X$ in distribution and $c$ is a constant. How do we show that $X_n+c \to X+c$ in distribution? It is intuitive that the constant should not change the distribution of $X_n$ but how do we describe it mathematically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u know that measures are stable up to translation

Answer (score 1):

Convergence in distribution simply means that $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ for all $x$ at which $F$ is continuous, where $F_n$ and $F$ are the CDFs for $X_n$ and $X$, respectively.

How can you write the CDF of $X_n+c$ and $X+c$ in terms of the CDFs for $X_n$ and $X$?

Comment: But $F(x-c)$ is not necessarily continuous at the point $x-c$, right?

Comment: Would it not be better to apply the Lévy's continuity theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem)? 

$X_n \to X$ in distribution $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow \phi_{X_n} \to \phi_X$ pointwise. Then: $\phi_{X_n+c}(a)=e^{iac} \phi_{X_n}(a) \to e^{iac} \phi_X(a)=\phi_{X+c}(a)$

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is the open interval $(a,b)$, we can let $S - c$ denote the interval $(a-c, b-c)$. Now note that for any random variable $Y$ we have $Y + c \in S$ if and only if $Y \in S - c$.

To show $X_n + c \to X + c$ in distribution, we want to show that $\mathbb{P}(X_n + c \in S) \to \mathbb{P}(X + c \in S)$ for every interval $S$.

But we just saw that $\mathbb{P}(X_n + c \in S) = \mathbb{P}(X_n \in S - c)$. Since $X_n \to X$ in distribution, we have that $\mathbb{P}(X_n \in S - c) \to \mathbb{P}(X \in S - c)$. And this is the same as $\mathbb{P}(X + c \in S)$. So we're done.

Now, if you are more comfortable with showing convergence of the CDF function, just use the fact that if $\phi_Y$ is the CDF of $Y$ then $\phi_Y(k) = \mathbb{P}(Y \in (-\infty, k))$. So taking $S$ to be $(-\infty, k)$ in the above shows $\phi_{X_n}(k) \to \phi_X(k)$ for any $k$.

Comment: The condition you stated in the second paragraph is sufficient, but not necessary, for convergence in distribution.  Standard example: take $S = (0,1)$, $X_n = 1/n$, $X = 0$.  Then $X_n \to X$ in distribution but $P(X_n \in S) = 1$ for all $n$ while $P(X \in S) = 0$.